# Add Account names from org in custom picklist

Tags: visualforce

I have to create a custom picklist where I need to add the values of all the Account names in my org .My requirement is I should not use querries because the account records are more than 1000 in my org .I tried to use the below code but I am only able to get the fields of the Account object in the custom picklist.I want to get all the account names that are in my org in the picklist.Please help me regarding this.

```
<apex:page controller="customPicklistController">
<apex:form >
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span></span>
            <apex:selectList styleClass="small" value="{!SelectedName}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </label>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

```
public with sharing class customPicklistController {
public List<Selectoption>Country{get;set;}
public string SelectedCountry{get;set;}
public List<Selectoption>Name{get;set;}
public string SelectedName{get;set;}

public customPicklistController () {

    Name= new List<Selectoption>();//new picklist to show the querryable objects in the org added
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType>schemaMap=Schema.getGlobalDescribe();//get all objects from the org
    system.debug(schemaMap);
    Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get('Account');
    system.debug('ObjectSchema@@@@'+ObjectSchema);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFields= ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    //Schema.SObjectField mapFields= ObjectSchema.get(Country__c);    
    system.debug('mapFields@@@@'+mapFields);
    set<String> fieldName=mapFields.keySet();   
    system.debug(fieldName);

    for(String field:fieldName)  { 
        Schema.SObjectField fieldvalue = mapFields.get(field);    
        system.debug('@@@fieldvalue '+fieldvalue );
        Name.add(new Selectoption(field,field));
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Describe calls return the structure of an object not information about the rows of an object. The standard way to pick an Account is a lookup field because that can handle an unlimited number. Why not use a lookup field?

Comment: @KeithC .I have to pickup the Account Name of all the account records and those account names should display as a picklist on vf page.SOQL query will not work here as the number of Account records are more than 1000.How will I use lookup field here to solve my problem.Please suggest me.

Comment: Why are you bothered about 1000 records? because the picklist will be too long? if so, you might have to come with a searchable picklist something like this - https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html since I'm not sure if you can get records with doing a query. also you could do this via remoting where you fire a query as user is done typing the account name

Comment: In a lookup field (e.g. an `apex:inputField` on an Account lookup field) a search dialog is automatically presented that allows the Account name to be found. This works even if there are millions of Accounts.

Comment: @KeithC The procedure you are saying is definitely working .But actually our requirement is to get the Account names in the picklist form .Will it be possible to construct a searchable picklist for this requirement because in that way  all the records will not be represented in one page and our limit will not be hit.Please suggest me

Comment: Yes you can build something yourself. I suggest you Google carefully to try to find some good code to use as a starting point and polish up your JavaScript skills.